# SWIFT How to obtain coordinate lat long from GoogleMaps GMSAutocomplete?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to obtain coordinates ( lat and long) after making an address selection from `GMSAutocompleteViewController`.

The relevant code is:

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name ?? "nil")")
    print("Place ID: \(place.placeID ?? "nil")")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
    //I try the following method, but the result is always -180 -180. Is there a way to obtain an address' coordinate from autocomplete?
    print("place cordinate: \(place.coordinate.latitude) \ .(place.coordinate.longitude)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)    
}
```

Comment: You got complete guide [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#add_a_full-screen_control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add below GMSPlaceField

```
 let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue:
        UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.addressComponents.rawValue))!
           autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `place` object to get the selected place coordinates. This is the working code from my project.

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(String(describing: place.name))")
        print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
        print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserLocation.coordinates = place.coordinate
        UserLocation.address = place.formattedAddress ?? ""
    }

}
```